# Make a category my homepage

Tags: categories

I've been trying every way, reading every post, to find out how to get my homepage to show category only. In my case, I will only like to show "travel"

I have tried another way is to set it as a menu first, however, the page does not show up as my home page, rather all my posts instead of posts only from the Travel menu unless I click on it

Is there a way around this, as in step by step will be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to 'modify' the main query to display posts from your specific category only. You will need to use the `is_home()` conditional to only target the home page of your blog.

The parameter `cat` that you are going to use in your query uses the category ID. You can also use the parameter `category_name` to display your category, just remember `category_name` is not the name of the category, but the **slug** of the category

You can add the following code to your functions.php. In this example, only posts from category 21 is displayed on the home page

```
function wpse_asc_cat_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', 21 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_asc_cat_pages' );
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) directly in your index.php to get posts from your selected category. You can change your loop to this

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 21
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    <---Pagination and rest of what you want to do--->      

    wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

Comment: Have my answer solved your problem. If so, please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark just below the up/down arrows. If not, how can I assist you in solving your problem